# androidでのプッシュ通知がバックグラウンド動作しない

Tags: cordova

cordovaを使用してハイブリットアプリを作成しています。

下記プラグインを使用してAndroidでプッシュ通知を行おうとしていますが、
アプリがバックグラウンドになった場合、プッシュ通知が送信されません。
アプリがフォアグランドの場合は問題なく送信されます。

下記参考サイトとほぼ同じに実装しています。
原因わかるでしょうか。

◎参考サイト
http://symfoware.blog68.fc2.com/blog-entry-1662.html

◎使用プラグイン
https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

◎実装コード（devicereadyのタイミングで下記を実行しています）

```
var pushNotification;

pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;

if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
    pushNotification.register(
        successHandler,
        errorHandler, {
            "senderID": 12345678,//実際は正しいIDを設定しています。
            "ecb": "onNotification"
        });
} else {
    // ios
    pushNotification.register(
        tokenHandler,
        errorHandler, {
            "badge": "true",
            "sound": "true",
            "alert": "true",
            "ecb": "onNotificationAPN"
        });
}

function successHandler(result) {
    console.log('result = ' + result);
}

function tokenHandler(result) {
    console.log('device token = ' + result);
}

function errorHandler(error) {
    console.log('error = ' + error);
}

function onNotificationAPN(event) {
    if (event.alert) {
        navigator.notification.alert(event.alert);
    }
    if (event.sound) {
        var snd = new Media(event.sound);
        snd.play();
    }
    if (event.badge) {
        pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, errorHandler, event.badge);
    }
}

// Android and Amazon Fire OS
window.onNotification = function(e) {
    switch (e.event) {
        case 'registered':
            if (e.regid.length > 0) {
                console.log("regID(device token) = " + e.regid);
            }
            break;
        case 'message':
            if (e.foreground) {
                alert(e.payload.default);
            } else {
                if (e.coldstart) {
                    console.log("=== message.background.coldstart ===");
                } else {
                    console.log("=== message.background.non coldstart ===");
                }
            }
            break;
        case 'error':
            console.log('error');
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
};
```

Comment: `ほぼ同じ`ということは、違う部分があるということですので、その部分が原因なのではとまず考えられます。コード全文を載せていただけると、回答の助けになると思います。

Comment: コメントいただきありがとうございます。
実装箇所質問本文に記載させていただきました。

Answer (score 1):

AndroidManifestに以下のパーミッションがない時、質問の現象のようになりますが、
どうでしょうか。

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
ご指摘いただいた下記パーミッションは設定ずみでした。
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />